# Show data in 1 listview from 2 tables

Tags: c#, mysql, listview

I have 2 tables in mysql and I'm trying to show them in 1 list view - is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible.may be you are looking for a Join query which brings data from 2 tables

Comment: ... or a Union if the two tables have similar schema.

Comment: You should try to improve your question next time. Have a look at these suggestions: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints Always write questions that will help as much people as possible in future.

Comment: Sure it is. But do you want a join, or do you want hierarchical. Do you want to brute force code it, or bind to a datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. Have a look at the [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) MySQL manuals.